# haproxy with miltiple backend

Tags: networking, load-balancing, haproxy, system-administration

We are trying to configure two back end with https in haproxy load balancing scenario.

We  tried ssl termination, hrd_beg ,   …         but could not come to expected result 
As in every configuration we tried requests are being transferred to default back end only and not to other back end.

Below is my configuration file.

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0 notice
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 debug 
        maxconn   5000                  # Total Max Connections. This is dependent on ulimit
        daemon
        quiet
        nbproc    1                     # Number of processing cores. Dual Dual-core Opteron is 4 cores for example.
        chroot    /usr/share/haproxy
        user      haproxy
        group     haproxy
        #stats     socket /var/run/haproxy.stat mode 600

defaults
        log                      global

        # Setting options
        option dontlognull               #Disable logging of null connections as these can pollute the logs
        option redispatch               # Enable session redistribution in case of connection failure, which is important in a HA environment
        option tcp-smart-accept         # Performance tweak, saving one ACK packet during the accept sequence
        option tcp-smart-connect        # Performance tweak, saving of one ACK packet during the connect sequence

        # Setting timeouts
        timeout connect           5s
        timeout client            1m
        timeout server            1m
        timeout http-keep-alive  10s
        timeout check             5s
        retries                   3

        # Slowloris protection
        timeout http-request     10s    # Slowloris protection
        timeout tarpit            1m     # tarpit hold time
        timeout queue             1m
        backlog                10000





frontend ap_ft_https
   bind                          *:443 ssl crt /home/mykey.pem
    mode                          tcp
    acl dcall url_sub dc
    use_backend dc_bk_https if dcall
    use_backend                   ap_bk_https if { hdr_beg(host) -i ap }
    use_backend                   dc_bk_https if { hdr_beg(host) -i dc }
    default_backend               ap_bk_https

# Configuration for AP Portals
backend ap_bk_https
        mode                      tcp
        balance                   roundrobin        # Load Balancing algorithm
        reqadd                    X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        #option                   tcplog
        default-server            inter 5s rise 2 fall 5
        server                    server1  x.x.x.x:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
#        server                    server2  x.x.x.x:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check

#Configuration for DC Portals
backend dc_bk_https
        mode                      tcp
        balance                   roundrobin        # Load Balancing algorithm
        reqadd                    X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        #option                   tcplog
        default-server            inter 5s rise 2 fall 5
         server                  server1  x.x.x.x:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
        server                    server2  x.x.x.x:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check

#HAProxy Stats configuration
listen  stats
        mode            http
        bind            0.0.0.0:8880
        clitimeout      100s
        srvtimeout      100s
        contimeout      100s
        timeout queue   100s

        stats           enable
        stats           hide-version
        stats           refresh 30s
        stats           show-node
        stats uri       /haproxy?stats
        stats realm     Admin\ Portal\ HAProxy\ Statistics
        stats auth      admin:xxxx
```

My Web addresses starts like apxxx.domain.com and dcxxx.domain.com.

I want to configure haproxy such a way that if request is for apxxx.domain.com then it should go to haproxy backend **ap_bk_https** and the same way if it is for dcxxx.domain.com it should go to haproxy backend **dc_bk_https**.

Your help will be **appreciated**!

Answer (score 1):

```
 /****************************************************/
           ROUTING BY SUB-Domain

     frontend http-in
          bind *:80
          acl app_ap hdr_end(host) -i apxxx.domain.com 
          acl app_dc hdr_end(host) -i dcxxx.domain.com

           use_backend ap_bk_https if app_ap
           use_backend dc_bk_https if app_dc


 Now all request from apxxx.domain.com and dcxxx.domain.com will be redirected to your respected backends.
 /**********************************/




 /*************** OLD ANSWER ************************///
        Basically what you want is to route by domain name.
        Here's an example which does exactly what you want. Have a look at it. Its simple .

       http://seanmcgary.com/posts/haproxy---route-by-domain-name

 /**  OLD ANSWER ENDS ************/
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It sounds good but in our case our domain names are same for both back end as i mentioned apxxx.domain.com and dcxxx.domain.com in this case domain.com is same difference is of apxxx and dcxxx and again how this will work on port 443. on port  80 it is already working!

Comment: Try this and let me know in case of any issues.

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    acl app_ap hdr_end(host) -i apxxx.domain.com 
    acl app_dc hdr_end(host) -i dcxxx.domain.com

    use_backend ap_bk_https if app_ap
    use_backend dc_bk_https if app_dc

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your need. Try it and let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: Paras, thanks for your kind reply, This sounds good but for me subdomain will not work as I have a route 53 and configure domains dynamically so apxxx mean it can be ap1.domain.com,ap2.domain.com,ap3.domain.com .....  and same with dc that can be dc1.domain.com,dc2.domain.com  ...... that's why we are trying with hdr_beg. Is there any way to configure this with hdr_beg?